# WPF: call Command in MVVM after view is rendered?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, command

I am designing a WPF app and using MVVM pattern. Let's say I have one view called `View1`, and it's `DataContext` is set to `ViewModel1` in it's contractor. The VM has one `Command`called `RefreshCommand` whose job is to calculate the data to be displayed on the view. Now I'd like to call this `RefreshCommand` right after my view is shown, but I don't know how to do that.

I tried to call it in the code-behind where I handle the `Loaded`event for the usercontrol, something like this:

```
Private Sub AfterLoad(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    RefreshButton.Command.Execute(sender)
End Sub
```

However, that's when I noticed that at this moment the `RefreshButton.Command` is still set as `Nothing`. Note that in the UI interaction the invoke of this button/command is fine. So when should I call the command to perform such operation? Thanks!

Comment: That looks like it should work. Show your XAML and viewmodel? It does sound like semi-strange request. I think normally I would just have my VM get its data immediately and show the data in the View via bindings. Are you sure you want the View to initiate the data loading?

Comment: @Alan Thanks for your reply. Of course it works! Now I just call the command's exec function in the last line of the contractor of VM. And it is working. This UserControl actually contains a AX Windows Form control (PivotTable from OWC), so the VM and View is somehow mixed up with each other: The VM must know the PivotTable member from the View. That's why I got confused. But anyway, it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: glad you got it working, I reposted my comment as an answer since you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it should work. Show your XAML and viewmodel?

Normally I would just have my VM get its data immediately and show the data in the View via bindings. Try executing the Refresh command in your VM constructor